# Contrast between background and main content degrades vertically

Tags: support, design

If you see the image below the contrast between the background 'grey' and the 'white' content degrades as you go down vertically which I think strains the eyes. Towards the bottom I can hardly distinguish between the background and the main content area. Can we have consistent contrast along the vertical dimension? See the red highlighted region in the image below. You see the same issue on the main site as well.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

But the content area where you are reading is solid. I have designed sites with this ambient background gradient and I think it is a pleasing effect. I'm not seeing this strain on the eyes but that's just my contrasting opinion.

Comment: Looking at the votes- I guess I am the only one with the issue! In any case, my take was that at the top my eyes tend to focus on the content between the left and the right boundaries and that is easier to do as the contrast between the background and content is clear. However, as my eyes go down the page, the lack of a clear demarcation confuses my eyes as I have to re-calibrate the area I am supposed to focus on without the visual aid of a left and right boundary.